# Prove that $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is denumerable.

Tags: real-analysis, cardinals

This is the third part of a question where the first two parts are to prove that (i) $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is denumerable (ii) $A_n = \{\sum_{k=0}^n x^n : a_k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is denumerable. I have these two parts done, the first using induction and the second by simply finding a bijection $f:\mathbb{Z}^{n+1} \rightarrow A^n$ and combining this with the result of (i).

The third part then says to prove that $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is denumerable. It seems to me that this follows directly from the two previous parts. It seems that part (i) should extend to an infinite tuple and then this could be easily mapped to $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. I am doubtful of this approach because it seems too simple and I know that intuition often doesn't hold when extending to infinity so I am wondering if I am overlooking some problem with this approach?

Comment: Part (i) does **not** extend to an infinite tuple.  Notably, $\Bbb Z^\Bbb Z$ is uncountable.  In fact, even the set of infinite tuples of elements from $\{0,1\}$ is uncountable

Comment: Rather, note that $\Bbb Z[X]=\bigcup_n A_n$.

Comment: To Omnomnom, I'm not sure I understand how that goes against what I was saying? I am only considering $\mathbb{Z}^n$ with $n\in \mathbb{N}$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ as it seems to me this is all I need to prove the result in the third part. In this case those counter-examples are not relevant are they? To Hagen, I see now how I can use this, thank you.

Comment: My point is that you have to be careful with what exactly an "infinite tuple" is if you want to answer the question by *"extending part (i) to an infinite tuple"*

Comment: "should extend to an infinite tuple" ... any argument with "should" in there is non-rigorous, right?

Comment: That makes sense Omnomnom I see what you mean now. To GEdgar I understand this I guess I was looking for whether there was a way for me to make that more rigorous or whether I needed to go for a different approach such as the union of the $A_n$ sets which I have now used.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $A_n = \{\sum_{k=0}^n a_kX^k : a_k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, i.e., the set of all polynomials with integer coefficients of degree at most $n$.  First prove $A_n$ is countable. Then prove that $\Bbb{Z}[X] = \bigcup_nA_n$ is countable.